# Speed up rendering background vector data in QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector, rendering, basemap

I have a geopackage of ordnance survey background data (field boundaries, rivers, roads, etc). I won't be doing any analysis on this data it will purely be used as a background / basemap.

My problem is that it's very detailed and quite slow to render in QGIS. Is there a way of speeding up the rendering somehow? I don't know anything about creating vector tiles but is that an option?

Comment: could you set it up as a WMS server and go from there, or apply a scale filter to the data's style

Comment: How would I set it up as a WMS? Would that require PostGIS / Geoserver?

Comment: yes it would need at least geoserver

Comment: If you only need a local image in the background you can also export your mapcanvas as an image with the worldfile option and load it as georeferenced image

Comment: @IanTurton would it be possible to set up a WMS from geoserver which is purely local and won't encounter issues with firewalls etc? Also (the hard question) is it relatively easy to figure out?

Comment: @eurojam I was thinking about that but the study area is quite long and I'll be working at different scales so that would rapidly require either a lot of rasters or else very high quality rasters which would also cause rendering issues. Thank you though

Comment: It's pretty easy and can run locally - all you need is the platform independent binary, and the SLD files the OS provide

Comment: Does the layer have labels?

Comment: You might look at: 1. creating spatial indexes, 2. creating generalized versions for display, 3. the options for rendering of each layer (simplification, caching, multi-thread), 4. taking snapping and labeling off it if you can, 5. matching it's CRS to your project's CRS, 6 trying scale dependent rendering if you change scales a lot, 7. using simplified symbology if possible, etc. along with the usual storing the geopackage on a local hard drive.

Answer (score 6):

You could move the data into PostgreSQL/PostGIS.

This would allow you to make use of spatial indexes on the data and feature simplification in the database.

Comment: I second this, I always store my large OS datasets in PostgreSQL and the performance is normally much better. You could also consider setting layer scale visibility so it's not drawing at unneeded scales (i.e. do you need it at GB level?)

Answer (score 4):

Setting up a WMS for vector layers may be a bit overkill especially if you do not have experience setting up a GIS server, I'd recommend trying these two options first:

1. For each vector layer under Properties>Rendering set a Scale Dependent Visibility min/max value.  This will turn off certain layers that have many features at zoomed out scales.  Large vector layers scaled properly should draw fast still.
2. Under Settings>Options>Rendering, enable the Render layers in parallel using many CPU option and bump up the max cores value from 1 to 2 or 3.

Answer (score 1):

If your data is OS Zoomstack then you can run a docker image I have built with GeoServer and Zoomstack already installed.

```
docker run -p 3080:8080 ianturton/geoserver-2.16-jdk-8-zoomstack
```

Then add `http://localhost:3080/geoserver/wms` to QGis

[image]

Add the layer `zoomstack` and proceed as normal.

Comment: Hey, this is pretty good. I was wondering if you have a link for the actual dockerfile somewhere so I can see how it actually sets things up? Is the ZoomStack data packaged up with it, or does it download it fresh every time you set up a new container?

Comment: I don't seem to have a copy any more - don't you get to see the set up when you pull the image?

Comment: Only is so far as it's pulling a layer that's ~11GB, which I presume is the OS data. I don't know enough about Docker to figure out how to update the data if it's baked into the image though.

Comment: Ah never mind, I've done some reading about the `docker cp` command :)

Answer (score 0):

There are some quality tradeoffs, but for maximum speed you can **render as a raster basemap**.

If you operate only at one scale (more or less), just export as a raster and create a compressed .tif.

If you then change scale slightly, the biggest artifacts you will see are on **labels**. If this is an issue, create a theme in your project which turns off labels and a 2nd theme which is labels only, no symbology. Then **export the symbology-no-labels theme as a raster and use it as a basemap for the labels-only theme**. Note you will lose the labeling engine's functionality under the hood to move labels to not clash with symbology.

If you need to operate at multiple scales, you could export the raster at several scales and use scale-dependent visibility to define which copy is shown on the canvas.

Or you could pack those different-scale rasters into an **MBTiles**. See https://www.fulcrumapp.com/blog/mbtiles-from-qgis for a tutorial how to generate them, and [GDAL create mbtiles with differing image by zoom level](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/317690/gdal-create-mbtiles-with-differing-image-by-zoom-level) for how to pack them together.

Note MBTiles is implicitly EPSG:3857. Raster reprojection is fast, so if you're operating at a detailed enough scale in another projected CRS, you can use an MBTiles basemap with little speed or quality degradation. If you're using a CRS significantly different from Mercator at a more macro scale, you will see more artifacts. You are most likely to notice them on longer labels first.

I generate basemaps like this as MBTiles quite frequently, primarily for use in the field as imported basemaps in mobile apps. However, they are also effective -- with these limitations -- as fast basemaps within QGIS when the project emphasis is analytical and I don't want the overhead of QGIS creating beautiful maps all the time.