# Binding multiple Leaflet image overlays as one

Tags: leaflet, javascript, imagery

I am planning to put at least ten single image overlays, spread across the country. I have got two so far:

```
var priorycourt = 'Priory_court.PNG',
imageBounds = [[52.399892, -1.531154], [52.400837, -1.52945]];
L.imageOverlay(priorycourt, imageBounds).setOpacity(0.75).addTo(map);


var ipswich3a = 'A3Ipswich.svg',
imageBounds = [[52.0303, 1.19047], [52.0326, 1.19624]];
L.imageOverlay(ipswich3a, imageBounds).setOpacity(0.75).addTo(map);
```

Which won't look good, when it is 70 instead of 2.

I tried to put them in a different js file `img.js`,
although only very first is working, when in my main script remain

```
 L.imageOverlay(priorycourt, imageBounds).setOpacity(0.75).addTo(map);
```

Is it possible to create something analogue to `L.LayerGroup[priorycourt,ipswich3a]...` in order to combine all these image overlays together in one piece?

Comment: What is it that "won't look good"? Final outcome on screen will be the same if you add layers layer by layer or all of them at once as a group.

Comment: I want to add them as a group. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: Not sure if you just want to stitch the rasters together as in https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/192395/merging-tif-images-into-a-single-geotiff-with-qgis

Comment: Not particularly together, but I am going to have quite a few located randomly across the country. Is it possible to have them as a one layer likewise GeoJSON points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create layer group, add image layers to group and then add layer group to map:

```
var imageOverlays = L.layerGroup();

L.imageOverlay(priorycourt, imageBounds).setOpacity(0.75).addTo(imageOverlays);
L.imageOverlay(ipswich3a, imageBounds).setOpacity(0.75).addTo(imageOverlays);

imageOverlays.addTo(map);
```

or

```
var priorycourtLayer = L.imageOverlay(priorycourt, imageBounds).setOpacity(0.75);
var ipswich3aLayer = L.imageOverlay(ipswich3a, imageBounds).setOpacity(0.75);

L.layerGroup([priorycourtLayer, ipswich3aLayer]).addTo(map);
```

or

```
var imageLayers = [];

var imageLayers[0] = L.imageOverlay(priorycourt, imageBounds).setOpacity(0.75);
var imageLayers[1] = L.imageOverlay(ipswich3a, imageBounds).setOpacity(0.75);

L.layerGroup(imageLayers).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Perfect! Could I place it in the external .js file?

Comment: If by external .js file you mean what I mean you mean, then of course! And by the way, if answer helped you, basic politeness would require you mark answer as accepted or at least upvote it.

Comment: No worries, will do. For the time being I am involved in another section. For sure I will try your solution.

Comment: It works! I input it into the external .js and everything is alright. Thank you. I am upvoting with very heavy heart.